# Как извлечь таблицу из Power Pivot с использованием Python

Tags: python, excel, pivot, powerquery

У меня есть файл excel. В нем несколько сводных таблицы, но меня интересует источник для этих таблиц. Источник данных это запрос, но при этом в подключениях он отображается как таблица.
Если я два раза кликну по сводной таблице, то этот самый источник мне и откроется (только с применением фильтров разумеется). Мне нужно получить источник данных с использованием python.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно было бы реализовать?